# Cargar datos en un footable javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Amigos estoy teniendo el siguiente inconveniente, intento cargar los datos en un footable, lo intento hacer de la siguiente manera y no me funciona:

```
 $("#status").change(function () {
                var respuesta=new String();
                respuesta= "[{'id':'5629499534213120','Email':'andres123@gmail.com', 'cuenta':'fislatec', 'Nombre':'andres alba','Perfil':'Administrador', 'Estado':'Estados','Action':'Botones'}]";
                $("#tUsuarios").footable({
                                        "sorting": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "toggleSelector": ".footable-toggle",
                                        "columns": [
                                            {"name": "Nombre", "title": "Nombre"},
                                            {"name": "id", "title": "id", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Email", "title": "Email"},
                                            {"name": "cuenta", "title": "cuenta", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Perfil", "title": "Perfil"},
                                            {"name": "Estado", "title": "Estado"},
                                            {"name": "Action", "title": "Acción"}
                                        ],
                                        'rows':respuesta
                                    });
                        });
```

Pero de esta manera si me funciona:

```
  $("#status").change(function () {


                $("#tUsuarios").footable({
                                        "sorting": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "toggleSelector": ".footable-toggle",
                                        "columns": [
                                            {"name": "Nombre", "title": "Nombre"},
                                            {"name": "id", "title": "id", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Email", "title": "Email"},
                                            {"name": "cuenta", "title": "cuenta", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Perfil", "title": "Perfil"},
                                            {"name": "Estado", "title": "Estado"},
                                            {"name": "Action", "title": "Acción"}
                                        ],
                                        'rows':[{'id':'5629499534213120','Email':'andres123@gmail.com', 'cuenta':'fislatec', 'Nombre':'andres alba','Perfil':'Administrador', 'Estado':'Estados','Action':'Botones'}]
                                    });
                        });
```

Comment: La [documentación es clara , debe ser un array la opción rows](https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/getting-started.html#rows)

Answer (score 0):

En el primer ejemplo a 'rows' le asignas un string, mientras que en el segundo un arreglo de objetos.

Si los datos que quieres usar vienen en ese formato tal vez necesites usar JSON.parse() para tramsformarlos a objetos javascript válidos.

Answer (score 0):

El el primero estas enviando un solo string, mientras que en el segundo envías un arreglo de objetos. Solo ajusta los tipo de datos.

```
 $("#status").change(function () {
                var respuesta= [{'id':'5629499534213120','Email':'andres123@gmail.com', 'cuenta':'fislatec', 'Nombre':'andres alba','Perfil':'Administrador', 'Estado':'Estados','Action':'Botones'}];
                $("#tUsuarios").footable({
                                        "sorting": {
                                            "enabled": true
                                        },
                                        "toggleSelector": ".footable-toggle",
                                        "columns": [
                                            {"name": "Nombre", "title": "Nombre"},
                                            {"name": "id", "title": "id", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Email", "title": "Email"},
                                            {"name": "cuenta", "title": "cuenta", "visible": false},
                                            {"name": "Perfil", "title": "Perfil"},
                                            {"name": "Estado", "title": "Estado"},
                                            {"name": "Action", "title": "Acción"}
                                        ],
                                        'rows':respuesta
                                    });
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que dijeron tus compañeros, prueba con esto:

```
var respuesta = '[{"id":"5629499534213120","Email":"andres123@gmail.com", "cuenta":"fislatec", "Nombre":"andres alba","Perfil":"Administrador", "Estado":"Estados","Action":"Botones"}]';
respuesta = JSON.parse(respuesta);
```